# What is a strategy to properly shape arrays and vectors to avoid "could not be broadcast together" error?

Tags: python, numpy

This has happened to me several times with different equations, and right now, I struggle with it again. I am sure others have the same problem and look for a memorable strategy to shape arrays and vectors so that non-trivial NumPy computations go through without fiddling and poking.

This is the equation I want to implement: [image], where k is a scalar, and n, a, R and R0 are 3D vectors. R0 is a NumPy array holding four 3D vectors.

Now I get stuck in my workflow because I try to find a way to pierce together the NumPy calculation. I want to use NumPy's awesome parallelization for math and not break up the four 3D vectors and do a for-loop. I am not good enough at NumPy to "see" the shapes of intermediate result arrays. And so I end up with try-and-error, which gives ugly results and is unsatisfying.

Please don't just give a working solution but *explain* why you did what you did.

Here is my current code - which does not work as it should (the transposing of random arrays should not be there).

import numpy as np

```
def main():
    r_0 = np.array([[.265, 0, .382],
                    [0, .712, .764],
                    [0, .712, 0],
                    [.752, .712, .382]])

    b_measured = np.array([[1.64712096, 4.87716371, -0.77060129],
                           [1.55980676, 4.93977942, -0.7133636],
                           [1.40883668, 4.96624651, -0.71742247],
                           [1.6531721, 5.02004066, -0.72243437]])

    n = np.array([0, 0, 1])
    a = np.array([.2, 0, 0])
    r = np.array([0, 2, 0])

    r_relativ = (r - r_0)
    r_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(r_relativ, axis=1)
    error = -np.cross(a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T, n,
                      axisa=1) / r_magnitude ** 4 - b_measured
    print(error)


if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "3D vector" -> "3-element array" in bumpy terminology

Comment: Consider adding a detailed explanation of how the code doesn't work.

Comment: "I am not good enough at NumPy to "see" the shapes of intermediate result arrays." Use a debugger or print statements

Comment: lol, i do use a debugger, and i still spend a lot of time on the little progress i made, because i dont know what strategy to apply.

Comment: Your code has 8 statements. You can look at the arrays in each one in less time than it took for you to dump your code here.

Comment: It's a step-by-step process. Even when I see the following broadcast error, I need to understand why it happened and come up with a solution - and if nothing obvious comes to mind, start transposing. It's great that it's easy for you. It is not for me. I dumped this code here after spending several hours on the dumpster fire of code you see now.

Comment: Post the error traceback. Look at the shapes of the arrays involved. Debugging is all about precisely arranging ideas in your head. I'm not judging you, just pointing out what I think is wrong with your methodology so you can learn

Comment: thanks, i do want help :-)

Comment: Your missing the error traceback and any attempt to analyze the problem

Comment: The forest four paragraphs are cruft. The content of the question wouldn't change if you just deleted them.

Comment: hm, thank you for the feedback. i can certainly remove the whining, but there is actually the explanation what i want and why i want it. i can make that clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping track of shapes is a large part of `numpy` coding (and before that MATLAB).

First, I like to have a clear idea of the shapes of the inputs:

```
In [1]:     r_0 = np.array([[.265, 0, .382],
   ...:                     [0, .712, .764],
   ...:                     [0, .712, 0],
   ...:                     [.752, .712, .382]])
   ...: 
   ...:     b_measured = np.array([[1.64712096, 4.87716371, -0.77060129],
   ...:                            [1.55980676, 4.93977942, -0.7133636],
   ...:                            [1.40883668, 4.96624651, -0.71742247],
   ...:                            [1.6531721, 5.02004066, -0.72243437]])
   ...: 
   ...:     n = np.array([0, 0, 1])
   ...:     a = np.array([.2, 0, 0])
   ...:     r = np.array([0, 2, 0])
   ...: 
In [2]: r_0.shape
Out[2]: (4, 3)
In [3]: b_measured.shape
Out[3]: (4, 3)
```

The rest are (3,)

While one can use the debugger, I prefer to test code in an interactive session like `ipython`.

```
In [4]: r_relativ = (r - r_0)     # this was a (4,3) broadcasting with (3,)
In [5]: r_relativ.shape
Out[5]: (4, 3)
```

`norm` with axis, is like `sum`, `mean` etc, a reduction function, removing a dimension:

```
In [6]: r_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(r_relativ, axis=1)
In [7]: r_magnitude.shape
Out[7]: (4,)
```

though it is possible retain that dimension as a broadcastable size 1:

```
In [8]: np.linalg.norm(r_relativ, axis=1, keepdims=True).shape
Out[8]: (4, 1)
```

Your next line is complex, and the error doesn't identify the operator:

```
In [9]: error = -np.cross(a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T, n,
   ...:                       axisa=1) / r_magnitude ** 4 - b_measured
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-9-8d7646046c43>", line 1, in <module>
    error = -np.cross(a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T, n,
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) (4,)
```

Looking at the individual pieces:

```
In [10]: np.matmul(r_relativ, a).shape
Out[10]: (4,)
```

This is a (4,3) with (3,) producing a (4,).  (Also `matmul` issues different error messages).

```
In [11]: (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T.shape
Out[11]: (4, 3)
```

The `cross` argument looks ok.  `cross` itself runs.  I don't use it enough to remember the exact `axis` arguments, though the basic operation is for a pair of (N,3) arrays

```
In [13]: np.cross(a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T, n,
    ...:                       axisa=1).shape
Out[13]: (4, 3)
```

Finally, here's the error:

```
In [15]: np.cross(a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T, n,
    ...:                       axisa=1)/r_magnitude**4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-15-c4bed1fd9807>", line 1, in <module>
    np.cross(a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T, n,
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) (4,)
```

Why?  As noted the `cross` produces (4,3).  But `r_magnitude` is (4,).  It should be (4,1) to work with the (4,3).

In sum, I keep the 2 broadcasting rules upper most - it can add leading dimensions, and size 1 dimensions can be scaled to match.

The other issue is keeping track of how reductions like `norm` change the dimensions.  `keepdims` can be a big help here, though it's always possible to use `None` to add trailing dimensions.

I don't think there's any short cut to being pedantic about the dimensions.  Details matter.

With the (4,) correction to (4,1), `error` runs:

```
In [16]: r_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(r_relativ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
In [17]: error = -np.cross(a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T, n,
    ...: 
    ...:                       axisa=1) / r_magnitude ** 4 - b_measured
In [18]: error.shape
Out[18]: (4, 3)
```

---

focusing on the transposes.

```
a - 2 * (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T
```

the `matmul` produces (4,). `r_relativ` is (4,3); change that to (3,4), and it multiplies with the (4,). Transpose back to (4,3) so it can add to (3,), and work with `axis1=1` (default).

I think these should work as well (not tested)

```
a - 2 * r_relativ * np.matmul(r_relativ,a)[:,None]
(3,)    (4,3) * (4,1)  => (4,3)

a - 2 * r_relativ * np.matmul(r_relativ, a[:,None])
                     (4,3) @ (3,1)=>(4,1)
```

Comment: there is this ugly (r_relativ.T * np.matmul(r_relativ, a)).T part, is it worth to redo that? if so, and how can I avoid the transposing? if it is necessary, why? I mean I transpose twice. why can't I skip that? From the math point of view, those operations seem pointless.

Comment: See my new edits.

Answer (score 3):

This is a casting problem from numpy. In this line:

```
r_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(r_relativ, axis=1)
```

you are getting a (4,) shape, which is a vector, not an array. You can check that by adding a

```
print(r_magnitude.shape)
```

This generates difficulties with numpy casting, as numpy doesn't quite know how to cast this second undefined dimension. That is why you probably get the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) (4,)
```

Which means, you are trying to broadcast your vector r_magnitude (shape = (4,)) into a (4,3) shaped numpy array. To understand why this happens, you can check [this link to Tutorialspoint](https://machinelearningmastery.com/broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/). Towards the end they explain it.

What I believe is the standard, is to use the `keepdims` kwarg for basically every numpy method.

```
r_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(r_relativ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

This will make the operation keep the same number of dimentions as the original array (2 in this case), that is, r_magnitude's shape is now (4,1), making the broadcasting possible

Comment: Casting != Broadcasting

Comment: @alfonso-irrarrazaval can you please also speak to the issue of the (random) transposing of vectors and arrays? how do i need to structure the data (up front) to avoid that? and how do i know how to do that up front?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei. It's not random transposing. It's dimension reduction. For example, if you take the sum of a 2D array along axis=0, the first axis "disappears". The result is 1D. If you can wrap your mind around that, I'm absolutely sure you will understand what is happening here too